# How to search across a specific column range using Google Sheet "Find and Replace" feature

Tags: google-sheets

My spreadsheet has several tabs.

I want to use Google Sheets "Find and Replace" feature to find all instances of column C containing a specific value (across the different tabs).

I tried entering the `{'2023'!C1:C; '2022'!C1:C}` into `Specific Range` selector, but that did not work.

Any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Find and Replace" feature does **not** support multiple ranges.
You will have to do that separatelly.